# Rails - user selected filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I have a model Shop, database with attributes: shop name,year the shop was opened, total sales (and few more). I have done some statistics on this data and result of it is this table:

[image]

Now, what I want is to have the user select/enter the year, and the app to show the below data just for that year (instead of the whole table)

My shop.rb for table part:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :opened
  def self.percentile(values, percentile)
    values_sorted = values.sort
    k = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).floor - 1
    f = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).modulo(1)
    return values_sorted[k] + (f * (values_sorted[k+1] - values_sorted[k]))
  end

  def self.median_by_year
    arr ||= []
    years = Shop.distinct.pluck(:year).sort
    years.each do |yr|
      sales =  Shop.where(year: yr).pluck(:items_sold)
      perc = percentile(sales, 0.5)
      arr << perc.to_i
    end
    return arr
  end
end
```

my controller:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @count = Shop.count
    @sales_average = Shop.average(:items_sold).to_i

    @sold = Shop.pluck(:items_sold)
    @top_twenty_sales_average = Shop.percentile(@sold, 0.80).to_i
    @bottom_twenty_sales_average = Shop.percentile(@sold, 0.20).to_i
    @median = Shop.percentile(@sold, 0.50).to_i

    @average_sales_by_year = Shop.select('year, count(names) as count').group('year').order('year').average('items_sold')
    @min_sales_by_year = Shop.select('year, count(names) as count').group('year').order('year').minimum('items_sold')

    @med = Shop.median_by_year
    @table = @average_sales_by_year.zip@med.zip@min_sales_by_year
  end
```

and finally table in the view file

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Average sales</th>
            <th>Median sales</th>
            <th>Min sales</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @table.each do |avg, med| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= avg[0] %></td>
            <td><%= avg[1].to_i.to_s %></td>
            <td><%= med[0] %></td>
            <td><%= med[1][1] %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In order to create filter I tried bunch of stuff based on similar SO questions, but this is my first app ever, so basically I don't understand enough to know what to do. So far I tried to add this to the model:

```
  def self.by_year(selected_year=nil)
    if year
      where(year: selected_year)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

this to the controller:

```
@shops = Shop.select(params[:year])
```

and finally this in the view:

```
<%= form_tag url: shops_path do %>
        <%= select_tag :year  %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
<% end %>
```

but I don't really know if that is right, or how to continue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your controller index you have to add an if. 
@shop = Shop.select(params[:year]) if params[:year] . and in your form_for method: :get

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. But this still is not giving me actual filter, just an empty form.

Comment: You mean you get an empty form and then you enter something and hit the Filter and you still get an empty form? did you check your console log to see if any queries were run, did you try to <%= raise @shop.inspect %> and see if you see a list of shops as error mesage in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

it would probably be cleaner to create a view for your table and than have a separate model of that view  with the year scope

```
class ShopStats < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :for_year, ->(year) { where(:year => year)}
end
```

than in your controller you can have:

```
ShopStats.for_year params[:year]
```